# Python Client and NodeJS Server Simple Communication

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a NodeJS Electron app that is working great. I have a Python script that processes some video and also needs to send some short strings to NodeJS to display on the Electron app. I've been trying to get WebSockets to work and it seems to be having a lot of issues with Python-Node communication (compared to Node-Node), so I want to know if there are any simpler methods of inter-language communication before going all in on troubleshooting this.

Stdout is impractical I think as the Python script likely won't behave well running through Node. SocketIO seems to use HTTP which seems overkill for sending 40 bytes of data. Is there a super simple method of sending a few bytes over TCP perhaps? Or is SocketIO as good as it is going to get?

Any help is appreciated!

## My Solution

EDIT: After investigating socket.io further it is actually really simple overall! For future reference, here is my NodeJS server code:

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(6079); // import socket.io module and listen on port 6079

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.info('connection established');

    socket.on('msg', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        // do something with the message
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('client disconnected');
   });
});
```

And here is the code for the Python client:

```
import socketio
from time import sleep # just used for timing the messages

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print('Connection established with server to send message data.')

def send_msg(msg):
    print("sending")
    sio.emit('msg', msg)

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('Disconnected from websocket! Cannot send message data.')

sio.connect('ws://localhost:6079')

# list of messages to send
MESSAGE_LIST = ["66903222854465",
                "36558352171508",
                "42493680134299",
                "32010903761366",
                "37556732408598",
                "00418984412935",
                "54555467232969",
                "95461295964563",
                "63543734057786",
                "37925062203941"]

# logic to send the 10 messages then close connection
x = 0
while x < 10:
    send_msg(MESSAGE_LIST[x])
    sleep(1)
    x += 1

sio.disconnect()
```

I am not sure why it is so hard to find barebone implementations of server/client code (especially with cross-language implementations), but this seems to be it. Hope this helps!

Comment: did you made it??